# how to get the name of invocant as string in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

In perl, a class "Lamba" implements a method called "process".

```
use Lambda;
my $omega = Lambda->new();
$omega->process();
```

in the process method, how can we get the name of it's invocant?

```
package Lambda;
use strict;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self; 
} 

sub process {
    my $self = shift;
    my $invocant;
    #
    # ??? what is the variable name of my caller ???
    #
    # ie. how to set $invocant = 'omega';
    #
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: What name string would you want to get in this circumstance? The calling code is not in a subroutine and has no name

Comment: Reading your question more carefully, it seems that you want to know how to establish within the `process` method that the name of the object variable was `$omega`. This is an [*X Y problem*](http://xyproblem.info/), and is comparable to asking how to use data strings to name a variable. Variable identifiers are purely for the consumption of the programmer, and if you think your program needs to know them then you have a design problem. If you explain exactly what it is that you want to achieve via this mechanism then I am sure we could help you better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

I've just realised that you want the *name* of the variable that was used to call the `process` method. You can't do that without a source filter, because there may be several names all referring to the same object, like this

```
my $omega = Lambda->new;
my $aa    = $omega;
my $bb    = $omega;

$aa->process;
```

and there is quite sensibly no way to get hold of the name *actually* used to call the method

This is an [*X Y problem*](http://xyproblem.info/), and is comparable to asking how to use data strings to name a variable. Variable identifiers are purely for the consumption of the programmer, and if you think your program needs to know them then you have a design problem. If you explain exactly what it is that you want to achieve via this mechanism then I am sure we could help you better

---

#### Original solution

I've left this here in cased someone arrives at this page looking for a way to discover the name of the calling code

You can use the [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) function

A call without parameters like `caller()` will return the package name, source file name, and line number where the current call was made

You get get more detailed information by adding a parameter that represents the depth on the call stack that you want to examine, so `caller(0)` will return information about the *current* subroutine, while the values from `caller(1)` will be about the *calling* subroutine

If we change your main code to use a subroutine to call the method, then we can write this

#### Lambda.pm

```
package Lambda;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    bless {}, shift;
} 

sub process {
    my $self = shift;

    #
    # ??? what is the variable name of my caller ???
    #
    # ie. how to set $invocant = 'omega';
    #
    my $calling_sub = (caller(1))[3];
    print "Called by $calling_sub\n";

    return $self;
} 

1;
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Lambda;

mysub();

sub mysub {
    my $omega = Lambda->new;
    $omega->process;
}
```

#### output

```
Called by main::mysub
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can make it work with the `caller` function using line number.  I see what you mean about using variable names in other variables being a bad idea, and X Y problem, etc.

In this case  - "if you cannot find what you need with the caller function, then you are doing it wrong" - is a perfectly acceptable short answer.

Comment: @int: I really wish you would explain your purpose. It's far from true that any design involving `caller` is a good one, and my toes curl at the idea of code that varies its behaviour according to the *line number* where the call was made. In other words you're still doing it wrong, but there's no way we can help you unless you explain why you think you need this information

Comment: fair enough. Need to know which instance of Lambda called `process`, and do it all inside Lambda.pm. Lambda is large, dozens of member vars. In the main program there are many Lambda objects, and many existing main program scripts that I'm not gona change (due to laziness). There's a unique id in each Lambda object, but its inside the package scope-need something from caller's scope. Returns from `caller` won't be used in any decisions, just written to log to aid in identifying which Lambda instance in which main program had an issue. Really wish I could explain more but...600 chars

Answer (score 1):

The [`caller` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) returns information about the calling subroutine/sourcecode line:

```
sub process {
    my $self = shift;

    print join(', ',caller(0)); # Some of these values will be undef!
}
```

The [manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html)  shows this example:

> ```
> ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
> $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
>  = caller($i);
> ```

Increase `$i` to walk further through the stacktrace (reverse list of callers):

```
my $i = 0;
while (my @ci = caller($i++)) {
    print "$i. ".$ci[1].':'.$ci[2]."\n";
}
```

Starts with `$i=0` and increases `$i` *after* passing it to the `caller()` function. Prints a stacktrace back to the line of the script starting the current process.